# Routing VM with two IPs in the same subnet

Tags: linux, linux-networking, static-routes

I have two NICs with IPs in the same subnet.

IP1: 10.10.10.142 - Gateway: 10.10.10.129 - dev: ens192.
IP2: 10.10.10.143 - Gateway: 10.10.10.129 - dev: ens256.

I want to configure static route to the IP [192.168.1.5] as following:

192.168.1.5 via  10.10.10.129 dev ens192

192.168.1.5 via  10.10.10.129 dev ens256

Now I have an issue that when [192.168.1.5] send to [10.10.10.143] I'm getting reply from [10.10.10.142].

How can I fix the static route to reply from the same IP which is receiving?

Comment: protocol is SCTP and it M3UA Application Server

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct Tom Yan, and I apologize for the incorrect information provided earlier. The rule I mentioned does not make sense in this context, and your observation about the desired behavior is accurate.

If the goal is to reply to traffic from 192.168.1.5 using the same NIC and IP address to which the original traffic was sent, you should indeed rely on connection tracking (`conntrack`) and marking packets appropriately.

Here's how you can achieve this using `conntrack` and marking packets:

1. **Delete the conflicting static route:**

   If you want traffic from 192.168.1.5 to reach its destination correctly, remove the conflicting static route:

   ```bash
   ip route del 192.168.1.5 via 10.10.10.129 dev ens192
   ```
2. **Configure `conntrack` and packet marking:**

   You can use `iptables` to mark packets based on their source IP address when they leave the system. For example, if traffic comes from 192.168.1.5 via ens192, mark it as follows:

   ```bash
   iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.1.5 -o ens192 -j MARK --set-mark 1
   ```

   And if traffic comes from 192.168.1.5 via ens256, mark it like this:

   ```bash
   iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.1.5 -o ens256 -j MARK --set-mark 2
   ```
3. **Create routing tables for each mark:**

   Create two custom routing tables for each mark, which will determine the outgoing interface:

   ```bash
   echo "1 nic1" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
   echo "2 nic2" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
   ```
4. **Add routes for each routing table:**

   Now, add the routes to the two custom routing tables, specifying the outgoing interface and gateway:

   For table "nic1":

   ```bash
   ip route add default via 10.10.10.129 dev ens192 table nic1
   ```

   For table "nic2":

   ```bash
   ip route add default via 10.10.10.129 dev ens256 table nic2
   ```
5. **Create `ip rule` entries to select the routing table based on marks:**

   Create rules that select the routing table based on the mark:

   For traffic marked as "1" (ens192):

   ```bash
   ip rule add fwmark 1 table nic1
   ```

   For traffic marked as "2" (ens256):

   ```bash
   ip rule add fwmark 2 table nic2
   ```
6. **Flush the routing cache:**

   ```bash
   ip route flush cache
   ```

With these changes, packets from 192.168.1.5 should be marked correctly based on their source interface, and the corresponding routing table and interface should be used for the reply. This should ensure that traffic from 192.168.1.5 receives replies from the same interface it was originally sent through.

Comment: The ip rule you give doesn't make any sense. Why would a `from 192.168.1.5` rule matter to traffics that *destined* at `192.168.1.5`? And even if you mean `to 192.168.1.5`, it wouldn't make much sense either. If the OP wants to always use one NIC /source IP for traffics to `192.168.1.5`, why not just delete the other route? Obviously he wants to use *either*, depending on which the original traffic (from `192.168.1.5`) were coming at, which means he need fwmark rules and the help of ct mark.

Comment: Yes sorry, you are correct.. I have updated my post

Comment: `-s 192.168.1.5` At the *very least*, it should be `-d`. Besides, I highly doubt that just matching with `-o` and set mark in the OUTPUT chain could get it work. Most likely you'd need to set *ct mark* for the *connection* upon receiving the original traffics and set *mark* for the replying traffics based on the *ct mark*. (In addition, I don't know if it's a good or bad idea to remove any of the route in the main table, since they *might* help prevent any rp filtering from kicking in.)

Comment: In other words, *I think* before a route is chosen, the output interface of the replying traffics is likely not set, and once it's set, it probably takes more than just a route choice to change it. (Or, *I* don't think the problem here is that we need to *retain* the chosen outbound interface and source IP for the replying traffics.)